NG8001: 'app-servers' is not a known element
Error

Code


I have tried everything but failed to resolve
I am using same selector but not resolved
It should display label, input box and button.
I have tried the solutions given but not resolved my query

Include however the components are being "Declared" in a module or if they are "standalone" you'll need to import between the components (if no module).

Don't post screenshots of code please


Are you sure the name is correct? (Also check the selector defined in
the component)
Declare the component in a module?
If it is in another module, export the component?
If it is in another module, import that module?
Restart the cli?

